# How to fix Workflow Task Mails using the wrong URL in Mails in On-Premises?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

A simplified Version of the issue:

Server DNS Name is server-001
SharePoint is accessed using intranet.company.com

I have a List, that list has an EventReceiver, that EventReceiver creates SubWebs which have Workflows attached to Lists in it.

When a Workflow creates a Task, that Task will link to "http://server-001/xyz", but it should link to "https://intranet.company.com/xyz".

How can I fix this behaviour without having to change the whole SharePoint configuration? I have access to the complete EventReceiver code, Workflows, etc.

I'd ideally not want to remake the Workflows, however, since SharePoint Designer does not deal well with reusable Workflows and Content Types.

Answer (score 1):

If SharePoint itself is returning the wrong domain, then it sounds as though your alternate access mappings are misconfigured. I would recommend ensuring these mappings are configured correctly.

[Configure alternate access mappings for SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings)